# Printing unknown characters after reading string from a file

Tags: c

I have a function to read from a file:

```
void input(char* buffer, FILE* fp)
{
    char temp[100];
    fgets(temp,100,fp);
    strcpy(buffer,temp);
    buffer [strlen(buffer)-1]=0;
}
```

And I file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

The last line terminates with a newline.
I try to read the file this way:

```
FILE* fp=fopen("myfile.txt","r");
while(!feof(fp))
{
    char buffer[100];
    input(buffer,fp);
    puts(buffer);
}
```

It reads succesfully all the five strings: "1","2","3","4","5" and prints them, but after the 5th string is printed, I get segmentation fault.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a toy example not intended for production?  It has several issues, such as what @FatalError notes.

Comment: It should always be considered a hard programming error if you have an input operation (like your `fgets`) whose return value is not immediately used in a conditional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common anti-pattern in C (and other languages, really) to set up a loop like yours that checks `!feof(fp)`. The problem is that this function returns true only *after* a read has failed due to EOF. The issue is that you use the results of your read before you check if the read even succeeded.

I suggest you check the return value of `fgets()`, it will return `NULL` if there is an EOF. Propagate that value back and return it from your `input()` function. Then use that in your loop condition.

Just to add, the seg fault itself is likely in your call to `strcpy()`. When `fgets()` fails, you attempt to copy a buffer of uninitialized data, which could contain literally anything and `strcpy()` may find a "string" much longer than your buffer. Even if it happens to find something shorter, your result will still be garbage.

Comment: This was the cause, and indeed some times I was getting segmentation fault, but some other times I was seeing printed on the screen strings with unknown characters.

Answer (score 1):

looks like

```
buffer [strlen(buffer)-1]=0;
```

At the last blank line, strlen is 0, and buffer is being set outside its range.

Answer (score -2):

The characters which indicates the end of a string isn't '0' but '\0' so replace this line:

```
  buffer [strlen(buffer)-1]=0;
```

by

```
  buffer [strlen(buffer)-1]='\0';
```

and it should be fine :)

Comment: Using '\0' is often considered good practice but it's actually the same as 0.  It's not causing the segfault